# Kernel address of USER objects

Tags: windows, object, windows-8

Can someone tell me how to get address of USER objects in paged pool on windows 8 (some code or any ideas)?
F.e. on win 7 we can do this by min. 2 ways: by CsrClientConnectToServer and gSharedInfo.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: On this page there is now any methods for getting user objects address are describing.

Comment: They are not stored there.  Your question isn't answerable.

Comment: Could you please decribe what you mean in phrase "They are not stored there"? And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here are some of the articles which may help you in finding your answer..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810501.aspx

Object Manager is the centralized resource broker in the Windows NT line of Operating Systems, which keeps track of the resources allocated to processes. It is resource-agnostic and can manage any type of resource, including device and file handles. All resources are represented as objects, each belonging to a logical namespace for categorization and having a type that represents the type of the resource, which exposes the capabilities and functionalities via properties.

An object is kept available until all processes are done with it; Object Manager maintains the record of which objects are currently in use via reference counting, as well as the ownership information. Any system call that changes the state of resource allocation to processes goes via the Object Manager.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)

Something about Kernal Objects and their difference from the GDI/User Objects

http://windowsarchitecture.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/kernel-objects-%E2%80%9Care%E2%80%9D-different-from-gdi-user-objects/

Here is an article which may give you some idea about paged pool in the kernal..

http://vishu25.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/kernelmemory/

And below paper will surely help you in your deeper study...

www.mista.nu/research/MANDT-kernelpool-PAPER.pdf

Let me know if it helps you..

Comment: Thank you for some links! But I've used google before asking a question here. And i'm not bad in pool internals.